# Error creating a New SSIS Project with Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, ssis-2017

I need to create a SSIS project on VS2017 to build some ETL's. I just installed the SQL Server Data Tools from this link:

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer)

It explains everything, but I'm still getting this message every time I try to create a project:

[image: img]

I did install the SSDT for VS 2017 (standalone installer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Data Tools are required to develop business intelligence projects. But you must install Integration Services and Client SDK from SQL Server Installation since it is required to build projects.

Since you are using Visual Studio community edition (free) you can install SQL Server 2017 Developer edition (free).

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Also make sure you have checked SQL Server Integration Services in Visual Studio SSDT installer.

Comment: I did reinstall the tools and then it work as expected. Thanks!